# I am trying to import data from an external device via an ethernet connection into python using sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I cannot tell if i am actually recieving data from this external device and I am then trying to import that data into a tkinter application which I believe that I am able to do, but we'll see. I am very new to this so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Code shown below.

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit
import struct
import time

host = "192.168.25.247"
port = 50000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

conn,addr = s.accept()
Print("Connected by ",addr)
s.recv()
```

Comment: does it print "connected by (some address)"

Comment: hello user253751, yes it does